# Is the body of a while statement a block?

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, scope

As the title says, I'm getting confused about the difference between blocks and "normal" pieces of code that follow a statement.

I usually enclose the body of a while loop in Ruby with `do`...`end`, e.g.

```
while true do
  # ...
end
```

But is it a block? If yes, why? If no, why is it declared as we declare blocks with methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while` is not a method but a [keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/keywords_rdoc.html). This allows it to have its very own syntax (e.g. to make the `do` optional) and evaluation rules.

The body of a `while` loop is not a block. Blocks are sent to methods and `while` is not a method. You can't pass a block argument to `while` (as in `while(true, &block)`) or refer to the body of a `while` loop or pass it around. It also doesn't create a new variable scope like blocks do.

> why is it declared as we declare blocks with methods?

I assume it's out of convenience. Why would you use a different syntax if there's already `do` and `end`? Re-using the same syntax for similar constructs (the body of a `while` loop, the body of a block, the body of a method etc.) makes it easier to read and write code.